# Как решить проблему: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-notification, android-alarm-manager

Всем привет. Я тут решил в своё android-приложение календаря добавить уведомления (Notifications) по времени с помощью AlarmManager. Но у меня появилась проблема: при вызове функции `notifyUser()` по нажатии на кнопку, которая отвечает за вывод уведомления(её вызов происходит в другом классе), приложение "вылетает" с ошибкой: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.masterok.calendar.Notes.notifyUser()' on a null object reference` Как мне это устранить? Код в тех местах, где вызывается эта функция, будет ниже.

Options.java(тот класс в котором как раз и "вылезла" эта ошибка):

```
public class Options extends AppCompatActivity {
  
    public Notes notes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);
        
    }

    public  void onClickGreen(View view) {
        notes.notifyUser();

    }
}
```

Notes.java(класс, где и содержится функция `notifyUser()` ):

```
public class Notes extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDataRecieved {
    final Context context1 = this;     
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "Calendar channel";
    private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 50;
    
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);
        
        onTimeSet(10,30);
    }
    public void onTimeSet(int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 1);

        if (calNow.after(calSet) == true) {
            // Если выбранное время на сегодня прошло,
            // то переносим на завтра
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        setAlarm(calSet);
    }
    public void notifyUser(){
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        } else {

            v.vibrate(500);
        }
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Notes.this, Notes.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Notes.this,
                0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(Notes.this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ikon_for_calendar_1)
                        .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                        .setContentText("Пора проверить заметки!")
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)

                        .setAutoCancel(true); 



        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(Notes.this);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, builder.build());

    }
    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {



        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent);

    }
```

Comment: А где у вас полю `notes` присвоено какое-либо значение? И тем более одна активность не должна обращаться к экземпляру другой

Comment: В логах у вас должна быть ссылка на строку, где ошибка

Comment: @ArtyMorris У меня в логах ссылается на эту строку:  `notes.notifyUser();`

Comment: Это ссылка на вызов процедуры. Должна быть ещё одна ссылка, внутри процедуры

Comment: Не должна - там написано что метод не может быть вызван, поскольку ссылка `notes` равна `null`

Comment: Перенеси метод notifyUser в класс Options